# Method or data member not found - TextBox

Tags: excel, textbox, userform

I have 2 textBoxs located in userform1, then I have 2 buttons that opens userform2 and userform4 respectively, when those userforms open, the user has the option to add some new info to the textboxs in userform1.

The problem is, when I click button 1 and try to add new info, it gives me the following error: method or data member not found.

I tried with userform1.textbox6.text and without: textbox6.text

But none worked

Here is a piece of code where I get the error:

```
 lr = Worksheets("CGI").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

 Worksheets("CGI").Cells(lr + 1, 2).Value = UserForm1.TextBox6.Text

 UserForm1.TextBox6.Text = ""
```

I appreciate in advance any help you guys can give!

Comment: I can only guess, but are you using `VBA` and excel? If so, I would add them to the tags or specify them in your question.

Comment: Hi Daniel, sorry.. forgot to mention, I'm using an excel sheet to draw the values that I have in the userform